# update content page from menubar primefaces 3 and jsf 2 ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

well first ill explain what im tryng to do, i have a index.xhtml page where i include menu.xhtml  with a menubar of primefaces, in menu.xhtml in have a panel id=contenido where i want to update depending of the menuitem clicked, i already get update that panel but the problem is when i update to another page for example in default is home.xhtml and i update to enviarsol.xhtml then the command button from enviarsol.xhtml is not working, im new at this and i already tried some different ways of updating the panel, im thinking that the problem is that the bean of enviarsol.xhtml is not managed or something like that,also im doing this way because i want to refresh only that panel and not all the page, someone help me please.

index.xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <img src="resources/homeheader.jpg" width="300" height="113" alt="homeheader"/>
    <div style="background-color: white">
    <img src="resources/Logos.jpg" width="1024" height="166" alt="homeheader"/>
    </div>
     <p:panel id="centerpage" >
        <ui:include src="WEB-INF/menu.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>`
```

menu.xhtml:

```
<p:menuitem value="Contactos" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w" actionListener="#{bnmenu.btnEditarContacto(e)}" update="contenido"/>  
<p:panel id="contenido" >
    <ui:include  src="#{bnmenu.url}"/>
</p:panel>
```

bnmenu.java:

```
private String url;

public bnmenu() {
    url="home.xhtml";
}

 public void btnEditarContacto(ActionEvent e)
{
  url="enviarsol.xhtml";
}
```

home.xhtml:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="border-width: 0px">
        <p:commandButton  value="Consultar" actionListener="#{bnhome.btnlogin(e)}" update="txt1"/>
    <p:inputText id="txt1" value="#{bnhome.txtUsuario}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
```

enviarsol.xhtml:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="border-width: 0px">
        <p:outputLabel for="txtcorreo" value="Correo: "/>
        <p:inputText id="txtcorreo" value="#{bnSolicitud.correo}"/>
         <p:outputLabel for="txtmensaje" value="Mensaje: "/>
         <p:inputText id="txtmensaje" value="#{bnSolicitud.mensaje}"/>
         <p:commandButton  value="Enviar" actionListener="#{bnSolicitud.btnSolicitar(e)}" update="messages"/>        
</p:panelGrid>`
```

i included this:

```
<context-param> 
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name> 
    <param-value>false</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

and now it is working but i dont know what more effects will this cause
well now it works but only once when i click in commandbutton from enviarsol.xhtml
Finally it appears working fine, i changed @RequestScoped by @SessionScoped in bnmenu

Comment: Please look over your formatting, it is very hard to read your view code. All code should be indented with 4 spaces to format them correctly, using ` should only be used for very short in-liners

Comment: thanks now is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really want ajax navigation? It is very frustrating for a user not being able to use the browsers urlfield or navigation buttons, and it will be harder for you to code aswell. Consider transforming index.xhtml into a template file as described at http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example and using normal navigation.

Comment: thanks now im considering it at this point it is turning frustrating, also there must me be a way to do it

Comment: Is there any special reason you are trying to do ajax navigation?